# How can this equation be viewed as the Bessel equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, bessel-functions, eigenfunctions

Consider the operator $\mathcal{A} = -\Delta =-\frac{1}{r}\frac{d^2}{dr^2}r $ (spherical coordinates with symmetry). I am looking for eigenvalues $\lambda_k$, eigenfunctions $\varphi_k$ for it.

$$\mathcal{A}\varphi_k=\lambda_k\varphi_k \iff$$
$$\varphi''_k + \frac{2}{r}\varphi_k'+\lambda_k\varphi_k = 0.$$

Now, I'm looking at a solution of this problem and at this step the author considers this equation the "Bessel Equation" and uses the ready solutions for it and if I do this to, I get the correct answer. However, in my table of formulae the bessel equation is defined as
$$u''+\frac{1}{r}u'+\left(\lambda-\frac{v^2}{r^2}\right)u = 0$$
I realize that $v$ can be $0$. But how is this definition consistent with what I have above, with the $2$ instead of a $1$ in the second term?

Comment: Have you tried changes of variable such as $r = a x^b$.

Comment: @Aruralreader Do you mean that a variable change would make me realize that it actually is the Bessel equation, or just that it can be solved that way? Because I'm not interested in tips to solving the problem, I want to understand why the specific method, i.e considering it the Bessel equation, works.

Comment: You’re trying to see how one ODE can represent another. A pretty typical starting place is to look for simple changes of variable that transform one into the other, in your case, into the Bessel equation.

Comment: See [spherical Bessel equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalBesselDifferentialEquation.html)